# Custom Reports using xunit in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, report, jenkins-plugins

I need to publish my custom reports which is in xml format which is currently in my system in the jenkins.Is it possible to publish on jenkins using xUnit.
If yes, how to configure it.please suggest some
ideas

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Jenkins [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)

The Jenkins WIKI page which I have linked to here has excellent documentation.

You will first need to install the plugin via the Jenkins Update center under Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Available tab.

Once installed you will see the options referred to in the WIKI page in the configuration pages.